# How to make Perl fall back to just execute without debugging when it fails to connect to remote host?

Tags: perl, remote-debugging

```
[root@ test]$ PERLDB_OPTS=RemotePort=localhost:1111 perl -d typeglob
Unable to connect to remote host: localhost:1111
Compilation failed in require.
 at typeglob line 0
        main::BEGIN() called at /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/perl5db.pl line 0
        eval {...} called at /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/perl5db.pl line 0
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.
 at typeglob line 0
```

As you see,when it fails to connect,the programe just fails and exits.How can I make it just run as if `-d` is not specified in **that case**?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the task you are trying to perform here.  Not sure why you're invoking the perl debugger here?  But I'm wondering if there's a return code from that CLI command?

If so, maybe you can write a shell script to execute perl the first way and if it returns a failure code, just change the CLI to execute without the -d switch.

So, in other words, there may be a perl way to do what you want but there are many ways to skin a cat...